# Content type with list of objects

Tags: 8, nodes

I am trying to create a content type (*Quiz Question*) in Drupal 8 that has a bunch of regular plain text fields. I also want to add a field that acts as a list of answers. Each answer should have a plain text entry and a boolean entry.

The data model for a node will look something like this:

```
    {
        "Question": "Does Drupal rock?",
        "Answers": [
            {
                "Answer": "Yes",
                "IsAnswerCorrect": true
            },
            {
                "Answer": "No",
                "IsAnswerCorrect": false
            },
            {
                "Answer": "You're a rock",
                "IsAnswerCorrect": false
            }
        ]
    }
```

Is there any way to do this without creating custom field types or entities using separate custom modules and plugins?

Comment: Why not simply use the Quiz module? Also, is this about D5?

Comment: There are also a handful of modules related to this that will do this too and Quiz is one of them

Comment: Sorry, I am using Drupal 8 and Quiz is not available.

Comment: No, you cannot achieve it without third-party modules. Out of the box, Drupal doesn't have a field that store a string and a Boolean values.

Comment: Well the overall answer to your question is, no, this is not possible without new field types, modules, or custom code. Vanilla Drupal won't facilitate this. You'd want at a minimum something like Field Collection or Paragraphs, which grant the flexibility but probably not helpful for quiz structure functionality. Also, you'd have to code the rest (scoring).

Comment: Thank you Kevin and kiamlaluno. I just wanted a quick solution to import some data in a quiz format. It might not turn out to be a quiz at all and I did not want to bring in a full module with all its dependencies. It seems a module that allows one to create custom field types could be useful. I'll add it to my endless "fun project todo"-list :P. Just need to brush up on PHP first, seems a lot has happened since D6 was introduced!